# Salary in foreign currency

Tags: salary, salaried-pay

What happens to one's salary when the value of the foreign currency falls against the currency of the country of which one is a citizen of & where one is  currently working and permanently reside in as well.

Comment: What is written on the contract?

Comment: @FábioDias, nothing's related to currency conversion or inflation is mentioned in the contract.

Comment: How is your pay denominated in the contract? If your pay is specified in the foreign currency, that is how you are paid. If the currency rises, you have more in your currency. If it falls, you have less. The opposite is true for the employer if denominated in your local currency.

Comment: There is no standard answer to this, as it is a company policy. You should check with the HR departament of your company.

Answer (score 9):

If your contract states that you receive $1000 in US, then that is what you are paid.

If the exchange rate at the time you signed meant you received £1200 in your bank account then that is fine.

If the exchange rate has changed and you only get £800 in your bank account while still being paid $1000 then that is not any fault of your employer...

Have a friend who transfers money home and is **very** careful about checking the exchange rates...

Comment: This happened to me 4 or 5 years ago when I was being paid in sterling (£) and living/spending Euros. The rate went from e1.4 /£ to 0.98/£.

Comment: @Justin it’s mean, happened to us when we were studying in France...

Answer (score 8):

Nothing.

Keep in mind, you don't even need to bring another currency into the picture to see this in action - ***it's what inflation is.***  If you have $100 on your paycheck... that $100 isn't worth the same the following year.  What that $100 might be able to buy you *now* is more than it will a year from now.  Or 5 years from now.  So imagine you're working for a US company, and you understandably take your $100 check to buy 30 bags of carrots.  Problem is, the dollar gets devalued, the price of carrots "goes up" (its not that it actually "went up", it's just that dollars are worth less) - and now you can only afford 27 bags of carrots.  Do you think the company should be required to immediately adjust your salary so you can still afford 30 bags of carrots?

Now, let's add another currency.  You get your paychecks, but instead of buying bags of carrots, you buy Yen.  The dollar lowers in value, and suddenly you can't buy as many Yen as you used to.  Why should that be any different than not being able to buy as many carrots?

... but it's even worse.  Imagine the reason you couldn't buy as many Yen isn't because the *dollar* lowered in value... but because the *Yen rose* in value.  Suddenly, you're not asking to get paid more because the dollar's worth less - you're asking because the thing you buy with your money is more expensive.  It'd be like asking for a raise because a farmer's strike made the price of carrots go up, and you're basing your salary perspective on "carrot purchasing power"

Comment: This is a very convincing answer. Monday morning I am going to demand that my boss begin paying me in carrots.

Comment: +1 just for the humor value.